# TRIGGER AFTER INSERT SELECT MIN(COUNT) insert ID

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a trigger after an insert on the `eventss` table. The trigger should select the `Bcoordinator_ID` from the `bookingCoordinator` table where they have the minimum number of occurrences in the `eventss` table.

Here's my table data followed by the trigger. It doesn't like the `minCount` in the values, I think it's looking for and int.

```
DROP TABLE eventsBooking
CREATE TABLE eventsBooking 
(
      EBK INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(100, 1),
      booking_ID AS 'EBK'+CAST( ebk as varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,

      bookingDate DATE,
      Bcoordinator_ID VARCHAR (20),
      eventss_ID VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO eventsBooking    
VALUES ('2015-01-07 11:23:00', NULL, 'EVT100');
```

`Eventss` table:

```
EVT INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(100, 1),
eventss_ID AS 'EVT' + CAST(evt as varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,

eventsName varchar(50), 
noOfStages SMALLINT, 
noOfRounds SMALLINT, 
eventsDate DATE,
entryFee DECIMAL (7,2),
venue_ID VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
judges_ID VARCHAR (20)

INSERT INTO eventss  
VALUES ('Swimming Gala 2015', '3', '7', '2015-01-07 09:00:00', '35.00', 'VEN101', 'JUD100');



CREATE TABLE bookingCoordinator 
(
      BCO INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(100, 1),
      Bcoordinator_ID AS 'BCO'+CAST( bco as varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,

      forename varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
      familyName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO bookingCoordinator VALUES ('Steve', 'Wills');
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGinsertJudge 
ON  [dbo].[eventss]
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO dbo.eventsBooking (Bcoordinator_ID, bookingDate, Eventss_ID)             
   VALUES(minCount, getdate(), 100)

   SELECT MIN(COUNT(Bcoordinator_ID)) AS minCount
   FROM eventsBooking
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an aggregation of an aggregation i.e. `MIN(COUNT(1))`

If you just want the Bcoordinatior_ID with the least counts in eventsBooking, do this

```
select top 1 bcoordinator_id 
from eventsBooking 
group by bcoordinator_id 
order by count(1) asc
```

And you don't use VALUES() in an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement

Also, in your current code, since eventsBooking.bcoordinator_id is always null, you need to join to the actual table of bookingCoordinators to return booking coordinators without any events booked.

So your complete trigger statement should be

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.eventsBooking (Bcoordinator_ID, bookingDate, Eventss_ID)                
     select 
 top 1
  bookingcoordinator.bcoordinator_id, getdate(), 100 
    from bookingCoordinator left join eventsBooking 
        on bookingCoordinator.Bcoordinator_ID = eventsBooking.Bcoordinator_ID
    group by bookingcoordinator.bcoordinator_id 
    order by count(1) asc
```

Comment: what do I put  in the values where I have minCount. I've tried putting in 1 but it only insert the number 1 into Bcoordinator_ID

Comment: oh I've just realised I forgot something, once it's found the Bcoordinator with the lowest count, it should insert the Bcoordinator_ID in the bookingCoordinator.Bcoordinator_ID

Comment: it says 'Incorrect syntax near 'end' what could that be

Comment: Do you have two ENDs at the end? You should only have one, I just copied yours so you'd know what to replace.